# While loop only executed once because of PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show data of some user from two tables: one table contains data except image URL, and one table contain the image URL.

I am trying to get the ID and other data first from one table, and from that ID I am getting the image URL from another table, but when I call the function for getting the image URL from the other table using some function, the while loop only runs once and the other data is not showing.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$Object = new Main_Class();
$result_show_latest_20_mat_users = $Object->show_latest_20_mat_users($logged_in_user_id);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_show_latest_20_mat_users))
    {
    $u_id = $row['u_id'];
    $mu_name = $row['mu_name'];
    // For Getting Image URL Of This Loop User ID
    $result_get_image_url = $Object->get_image_url($u_id);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_show_latest_20_mat_users);
    $u_profile_image = $row2[0];
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $u_profile_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $mu_name; ?>">
    <?php   
    }
}   
?>
```

Both the functions are working perfectly, but the problem is in – I think – the approach I used. Because of that, the while Loop is working only once and only one record is showing.

Comment: Can't you do a `join` and get all the data with 1 query?

Comment: The second call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` should probably get another argument: `mysqli_fetch_array($result_show_latest_20_mat_users)`.

Comment: Why don't you just use one query, with a join?

Comment: If it can be done with JOIN  , then please tell me
and how can i fetch data using that query to show it using while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this row

```
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_show_latest_20_mat_users);
```

with this

```
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_image_url);
```

Comment: Lolxxxxx.
Thanks Man.
I Forgot to Change that :)